# How can I retrieve the users friendslist and display?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

(Sorry for my english)

I am developing [a web application](http://livescoreapp.azurewebsites.net/) with php and Facebook php sdk 4.0. I'm using the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php to let the authorize access to their information. I take their facebook-id and store it in the database table Users {int UserID FK, nvarchar(max) UserName, nvarchar(max) facebook-id}.  I want to make a list of their facebookfriends who are using the web application. How can this be possible? I can't just change the row:

**new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );**

to

**new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' );**

?

```
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXX','XXX');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://livescoreapp.azurewebsites.net/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php
      if($conn === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }
    else //Connection to database is ok. 
    {
    // see if we have a session
        if ( isset( $session ) )
        {
          // graph api request for user data
          $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
          $response = $request->execute();
          // get response
          $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

          // print data
          echo  '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

            $fb_Id = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
            $fb_Name = $graphObject->getProperty('name');
            echo "HEY <a href='" . $fb_link . "'>" . $fb_Name . "</a>";
            echo "<br> Your fb-id: " .  $fb_Id; 

          //  if(CheckIfUserExistsInDatabase($fb_Id, $conn) == false)
          //  {
          //       InsertNewUser($conn,  $fb_Id,  $fb_Name); 
           // }

        } 
        else {
          // show login url
          echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

What this code prints out:

[image: a busy cat]
!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the user's friends, you must request the `user_friends` permission when logging the user in:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_friends' ) );
```

Then, you'll be able to call the API as follows:

```
$friends = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

[See my tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/) for a complete solution.

Comment: Hm, the array I'm returning is empty?

Comment: Oh, Now it works. Asked my brother to access the link

Answer (score 0):

The full solution then:

```
<?php

// added in v4.0.5
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

// added in v4.0.0
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

// added in v4.0.5
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

// added in v4.0.0
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'XXX','YYY' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://livescoreapp.azurewebsites.net/' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo $ex->message;
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data

  $friends = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends, 1 ) . '</pre>';



  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the 90 line in FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php .... it looks like

`public function getLoginUrl($scope = array(), $version = null)`

I change by

`public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)`

and works!!!  PD. Put in &scope  array the permissions you need.

Regards!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://{your-website}/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```